# VBA code to set x axis crossover dynamically

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble with this VBA code:  I want the x-axis crossover to be the last cell value in column A (data starts at A2 ......) so that every time the scatter plot data expands, then the x-axis crossover is reset to the value of the last cell in column A.   at rhe

Here is my VBA code (has a run-time error at the {Selection.CrossesAt = SelRange} line ):

```
 Sub Dyna()

 Dim SelRange As Range

 'This code moves down column A to the end of the list.


  ' Select cell A2, *first line of data*.
  Range("A2").Select
  ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
  Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
     ' Insert your code here.
     ' Step down 1 row from present location.
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Loop

 Set SelRange = Selection


' Create a chart based on the sample source of data.
 Charts.Add

 With ActiveChart
 .ChartType = xlLineMarkersStacked
 .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A5"), PlotBy:=xlColumns
.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet1"
 End With

 ' Set the category axis to cross the value axis at value 3.
 ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
 Selection.CrossesAt = SelRange
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
Sub Dyna()
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    'This will find the last row of data in Column A
    lngLastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row

    Charts.Add

    With ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlLineMarkersStacked
        'This next line selects all data in column A, from A2 to the last row of column A
        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngLastRow, 1)), PlotBy:=xlColumns
        .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet1"
    End With

    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    'This next line sets the axis crossover point equal to the last data point
    Selection.CrossesAt = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngLastRow, 1).Value
End Sub
```

If you change the name of the sheet you are running this on to anything other than Sheet1, make sure to change the code anywhere it says Sheets("Sheet1") to the new sheet name.